# I can't get data from context api in React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am trying to access all the data of this user by using the mail I received while logging in using the context api in react. For example, such as name, surname and other information, but the response from the context api returns empty, but when I try it in the postman like below, all the data of the users comes. I couldn't find where the problem came from. By the way, sorry if this question is duplicate because I couldn't solve this problem and I need to find a solution

**getDetailsContextApi**

```
import axios from "axios";
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { setUserDetailsContext } from "./SetUserDetailsContext";



export const getUserDetailsContext = createContext()


export const GetUserDetailsContextProvider = ({ children }) => {

  const { mail } = useContext(setUserDetailsContext)


  const [user, setUser] = useState({})


  const url = "http://localhost:64082/api/users/getUserDetails"

 

  useEffect(() => {

    axios.post(url,mail).then(response => {
      setUser(response) 
      console.log("response",response); //<--I'm printing here in the console, but nothing comes out in the console
  });
  }, []);


  return <getUserDetailsContext.Provider value={{ user }}>
    {children}
  </getUserDetailsContext.Provider>

}

export default GetUserDetailsContextProvider
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import IsLoginContextProvider from './Contexts/isLoginContex';
import SetUserDetailsContextProvider from './Contexts/SetUserDetailsContext';
import GetUserDetailsContextProvider from './Contexts/GetUserDetailsContext';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(

  <BrowserRouter>
  
    <IsLoginContextProvider>
      <SetUserDetailsContextProvider>
          <GetUserDetailsContextProvider>
            <App />
          </GetUserDetailsContextProvider>
      </SetUserDetailsContextProvider>
    </IsLoginContextProvider>
  </BrowserRouter>

);

reportWebVitals();
```

**postman**

[image]

**Controller web api**

```
 [HttpPost("getUserDetails")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> getUserDetails([FromBody]string mail)
        {
            return Ok(await _userService.getUserDetails(mail));
        }
```

**browser -> network->response error**

```
 {"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13","title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415,"traceId":"00-22f47a006272d34fa0a7f822ae28ccb8-c2f39a2fbaf9af41-00"}
```

**UPDATE: PROBLEM SOLVED**

This is how i solved the problem

I deleted the getUserDetails and setUserDetails contexts and moved them to a single context named userContext. and I updated the axios method as follows.

**userContext.js**

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";
const userContext = createContext()

export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const[mail, setMail] = useState()
    const[password,setPassword] = useState()
    const [user, setUser] = useState({})

    const values = {
        user, setUser,password,setPassword,mail, setMail
    }

     
    return <userContext.Provider value = { values}>
                {children}
            </userContext.Provider>
}

export const UseUserContext = () => useContext(userContext);
```

**LoginPage.js**

If the user enters with the correct mail and password, I set the mail and password.

```
import '../../Css/LoginPage.css'
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom"
import axios from 'axios';
import {LoginSchema} from '../../validations/LoginSchema'
import {useFormik} from 'formik'
import { UseUserContext } from '../../Contexts/userContext';



export default function LoginPage() {

    let navigate = useNavigate();
    
   
    const {mail, setMail, password, setPassword} = UseUserContext();

    const handleSignUpClick = () =>{
        navigate("/SignUpPage");
    }

   

    const { handleSubmit, handleChange, values, errors, touched } =
        useFormik({

        initialValues: {
            Mail:"",
            Password: "",
        },

     
        
        onSubmit: (values) => {
            
            axios.post('http://localhost:64082/api/users/login',values).then(function(response){
               
              
                if(response.status === 200){
                    setMail(values.Mail)
                    setPassword(values.Password)
                    navigate('/Login')
                }
                
                
            }).catch(()=>{
                
                window.alert("başarısız giriş !!")
               
            })

        },
        validationSchema: LoginSchema
    })
  


    return (


        <div>
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div className="logo">
                    {/* <img src={logo} height={100} width={100} /> */}
                </div>
                <div className="text-center mt-4 name">
                    PRIMEFOR
                </div>
                <form className="p-3 mt-3" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
               
                    <div className="form-field d-flex align-items-center">
                        <span className="far fa-user"></span>
                        <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="Mail"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        value={values.Mail} 
                        id="Mail" 
                        placeholder="e-mail" />
                    </div>

                    {errors.Mail && touched.Mail && (
                        <div >{errors.Mail}</div>
                    )}

                    <div className="form-field d-flex align-items-center">
                        <span className="fas fa-key"></span>
                        <input 
                        type="password"
                        name="Password"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        value={values.Password} 
                        id="pwd" 
                        placeholder="Password" />
                    </div>
                    
                   
                    {errors.Password && touched.Password && (
                        <div >{errors.Password}</div>
                    )}


                    <button type='submit' className="btn mt-3">Login</button>

                </form>

                <div className="text-center fs-6">
                    <button href="#">Forget password?</button> or 
                    <button href="*" onClick={() => handleSignUpClick()}>Sign up</button>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    );


}
```

**Login.js**

```
import { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { isLoginContext } from "../../Contexts/isLoginContex";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { UseUserContext } from "../../Contexts/userContext";
import axios from "axios";
import { toUnitless } from "@mui/material/styles/cssUtils";

export default function Login() {

    const url = "http://localhost:64082/api/users/getUserDetails"
    const {setLogin} = useContext(isLoginContext)
    const {mail, user, setUser} = UseUserContext();
    
    function notifySuccess () {
     
       setLogin(true)
    
    }
    
    

    useEffect(() => {
        if(localStorage.getItem("userMail")){
            axios.post(url,localStorage.getItem("userMail"), {
                headers: {
                  "content-type": "application/json",
                },
              })
            .then(response =>{
                setUser(response.data); 
                localStorage.setItem("userMail",response.data.mail);
            })   
        }else {
            axios.post(url,mail, {
                headers: {
                  "content-type": "application/json",
                },
              })
            .then(response =>{
                setUser(response.data); 
                localStorage.setItem("userMail",response.data.mail);
            })
        }
   
            })


    return (
        <div>

            <h1>Login .... </h1>
            <div>
                {
                    user.name
                }
            </div>
            
        </div>
    )

}
```

**Old axios**

```
        axios.post(url,mail).then(response => {
          setUser(response) 
          console.log("response",response); //<--I'm printing here in the console, but nothing comes out in the console
      });
```

**Updated axios**

```
axios.post(url,mail, {
                    headers: {
                      "content-type": "application/json",
                    },
                  })
                .then(response =>{
                    setUser(response.data); 
                    localStorage.setItem("userMail",response.data.mail);
                })
```

Comment: Try `fetch` api and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so there are multiple steps you need to take that you missed above.

First in this file

**getDetailsContextApi**

You are not parsing the response data into a JavaScript object, and that's probably the reason you're not seeing any result in the console. Also I used the `JSON.stringify` to convert the mail object to a JSON object coz that's what probably causing that `400 error code` in the network tab of browser DevTools.

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { setUserDetailsContext } from "./SetUserDetailsContext";



export const getUserDetailsContext = createContext()


export const GetUserDetailsContextProvider = ({ children }) => {

  const { mail } = useContext(setUserDetailsContext)


  const [user, setUser] = useState({})


  const url = "http://localhost:64082/api/users/getUserDetails"

 

  useEffect(() => {

    axios.post(url,JSON.stringify(mail)).then(response => response.json()).then((data) => {
      setUser(data) 
      console.log("response",response); //<--I'm printing here in the console, but nothing comes out in the console
  });
  }, []);


  return <getUserDetailsContext.Provider value={{ user }}>
    {children}
  </getUserDetailsContext.Provider>

}

export default GetUserDetailsContextProvider
```

Comment: I'm getting this right now 415 unsopperted madia type .I'm not getting 400 bad request

Comment: I'd love to take a look at the backend code. Something isn't right. In the Postman image in the post you sent the email directly without even including it in a JSON object, and it seems to work.

Comment: @NewPartizal Maybe remove the `JSON.stringify` method I added above, it's irrelevant, Axios will send it as a JSON anyway given it's a plain text.